# POSt method for AJAX dynamically created input fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using MVC and razor.

I have sucessfully implemented a way for the user to dynamically add more input rows at a click of a button (using AJAX and following Steven Sanderson's blog). **BUT** I do not know how to save the data to a database that the user inputs in these dynamically created fields.

I use his helper class, that quite frankly I am struggling to understand at all.

My question is what do I need to put in the POST create method. The link to the code in his blog is here:
[steven sanderson's blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)

Just a pointer in the right direction is all I need. THis is my current code:

**New row partial view:**

```
@model ef_tut.ViewModels.ClaimsViewModel

@using ef_tut.WebUI.Helpers
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("claims"))
    {
        <table class="editorRow">
   <tr >
                       <td>
          SubmissionUserID:  @Html. EditorFor (o.claim.SubmissionUserID)
                           </td>
                                       <td>
           ClaimID: @Html.EditorFor(o => o.claim.ClaimID)
            </td>
                                      <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(o => o.claim.ApprovedYN)
            </td>
                                                     <td>
            ClaimID(claimlinetable)@Html.EditorFor(o => o.claimline.ClaimID)
            </td>

       <td>
          ClaimantUserID:  @Html.EditorFor(o => o.claimline.ClaimantUserID)
            </td>
                               <td>
           Hours: @Html.EditorFor(o => o.claimline.Hours)
            </td>
                        <td>
            MileageCost: @Html.EditorFor(o => o.claimline.MileageCost)
            </td>
                                              <td>
           TravelCost: @Html.EditorFor(o => o.claimline.TravelCost)
            </td>
                               <td>
          Hours cost: @Html.EditorFor(o => o.claimline.HoursCost)
            </td>
                                <td>
           Total cost: @Html.EditorFor(o => o.claimline.TotalCost)
            </td>
                                       <td>
           ProxyYN: @Html.EditorFor(o => o.claimline.ProxyClaim)
            </td>

                                       <td>
          CatID:  @Html.EditorFor(o => o.claimline.CatID)
            </td>
                                      <td>
           SubCatID: @Html.EditorFor(o => o.claimline.SubCatID)
            </td>
                                                          <td>
           <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
            </td>
               </tr></table>

    }
```

**Blankeditorrowmethod**

```
public PartialViewResult BlankEditorRow()
{
                return PartialView("NewRow", new ClaimsViewModel());
}
```

**My current POST method that creates new DB records but all fields are null**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ClaimsViewModel viewModel)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.claims.Add(viewModel.claim);
            db.claimlines.Add(viewModel.claimline);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

**Create view**

```
@model ef_tut.ViewModels.ClaimsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>claim</legend>

        <div id="editorRows"></div> 


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
   @Html.ActionLink("Add another...", "BlankEditorRow", null, new { id = "addItem" }) 
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**jquery**

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
    });
    return false;
});

$("a.deleteRow").live("click", function () {
    $(this).parents("table.editorRow:first").remove();
    return false;
});
```

**Steven's helper**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;


namespace ef_tut.WebUI.Helpers
{
    public static class HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions
    {
        private const string idsToReuseKey = "__htmlPrefixScopeExtensions_IdsToReuse_";
        public static IDisposable BeginCollectionItem(this HtmlHelper html, string collectionName)
        {
            var idsToReuse = GetIdsToReuse(html.ViewContext.HttpContext, collectionName);
            string itemIndex = idsToReuse.Count > 0 ? idsToReuse.Dequeue() : Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            html.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(string.Format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}.index\" autocomplete=\"off\" value=\"{1}\" />", collectionName, html.Encode(itemIndex)));
            return BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(html, string.Format("{0}[{1}]", collectionName, itemIndex));
        }

        public static IDisposable BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(this HtmlHelper html, string htmlFieldPrefix)
        {
            return new HtmlFieldPrefixScope(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo, htmlFieldPrefix);
        }

        private static Queue<string> GetIdsToReuse(HttpContextBase httpContext, string collectionName)
        {

            string key = idsToReuseKey + collectionName;
            var queue = (Queue<string>)httpContext.Items[key];
            if (queue == null)
            {
                httpContext.Items[key] = queue = new Queue<string>();
                var previouslyUsedIds = httpContext.Request[collectionName + ".index"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(previouslyUsedIds))
                    foreach (string previouslyUsedId in previouslyUsedIds.Split(','))
                        queue.Enqueue(previouslyUsedId);
            }
            return queue;
        }

        private class HtmlFieldPrefixScope : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly TemplateInfo templateInfo;
            private readonly string previousHtmlFieldPrefix;

            public HtmlFieldPrefixScope(TemplateInfo templateInfo, string htmlFieldPrefix)
            {
                this.templateInfo = templateInfo;

                previousHtmlFieldPrefix = templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
                templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = htmlFieldPrefix;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = previousHtmlFieldPrefix;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FormCollection, so instead of this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ClaimsViewModel viewModel)
{
}
```

You will have this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formCollection)
{
}
```

You should be able to get the value for any new fields you have created using their name like so:

```
var newFieldValue = formCollection["newFieldName"];
```